# Array getting reset in function

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

#### Scenario 1

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];

function isChanged(a) {
  a = [];
}
isChanged(a);
console.log(a);
```

#### Scenario 2

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];

function isChanged(stack) {
  while (stack.length != 0) {
    stack.pop();
  }
}
isChanged(a);
console.log(a);
```

**Why is the array not empty in the first function, but it is empty when I use the second one?**

Edit :

I played around the changing the variable by assignment, and overriding its property.

#### Scenario 3 - changing the property of object

```js
var a = {
  prop: "Stackoverflow"
}

function change(a) {
  a.prop = "stack"
}
change(a)
console.log(a)
```

#### Scenario 4 - changing the whole variable itself

```js
var a = {
  prop: "Stackoverflow"
}

function change(a) {
  a = {
    "prop": "stack"
  }
}
change(a);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek. Is it because of this? `Changing the value of a variable never changes the underlying primitive or object. However, changing a property of an object referenced by a variable does change the underlying object.` - from the link you referenced in comment

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, when you set `a = [];` you are only changing the local variable `a`, which (after the assignment) no longer has any relation to the global variable that happens to have the same name. In the second example, you are directly modifying the `stack` variable, which happens to be the same object as the global variable `a`. If you were to do `stack = whatever`, it would behave similarly to the first example.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I didnt understand `If you were to do stack = whatever, it would behave similarly to the first example. ` part. If I set stack = [], it would be similar to first example? - Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Because that would change `stack` to be a reference to a new, different object. It would no longer refer to the same object as before.

Comment: Another way to look at it: whenever you use `=`, you are changing the variable on the left to refer to a completely different thing than before. That's different from calling a method like `pop()`, which modifies the original object.

Comment: I played around it as you explained. So if I change the property, the it affects the parent scope, but if I use assignment, it creates a new variable? Is my example correct in question?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you have it right! Glad this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is because in the first a is an object reference, which is set to a new empty array. Where as the 2nd calls a function on that object reference, which will actually remove elements from the array you pass to your function.

Comment: But as far as I know, all the operations are contained in the function scope, it should not affect the parent scope. Isn't it?